# Why is the open() function deleting all the data in my file?

Tags: python, file

I was doing a project in which I had to make a multiclipboard.

It will create a file and save all the copied texts over there. The user can add as many copied texts as they want and they also can clear the multiclipboard.

Here's the code:

```
import pyperclip
import sys

jim = open('multiclipboardd', 'w')

# This will copy text to the multiclipboard
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and (sys.argv[1].lower()) == 'save':
    jim = open('multiclipboardd', 'a')
    jim.write(pyperclip.paste())
    jim.write('\n')
    print('The text has been pasted to the multiclipboard!')
    jim.close()

# This will read text from the multiclipboard
elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and (sys.argv[1].lower()) == 'list':
    kk = open('multiclipboardd')
    print(kk.read())

# This will delete the text of the multiclipboard
elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and (sys.argv[1].lower()) == 'delete':
    jim = open('multiclipboardd', 'w')
    jim.write('')
    print('The clipboard has been cleared!')
```

The name of this file is `panda.py`. Calling `python panda.py save` in the terminal should save the curent copied text to a file named `clipboardd` and it does!

However, when I try to run `python panda.py list` in the terminal, it is expected that it would print al the copied words on the screen, but it deletes them all! Suppose that before calling `python panda.py list`, `clipboardd` has 110 letters. Then after calling `python panda.py list`, it has 0 letters!

Why is the `list` command deleting all the characters inside the file? Is it the `read()` function?

Comment: `read()` isn't truncating your file. The unconditional `jim=open('multiclipboardd','w')` at the top of your file is.

Comment: `jim=open('multiclipboardd','w')` is expected to remove the data! Moreover, Python will reach `jim=open('multiclipboardd','w')` only when a person calls `python panda.py delete`

Comment: What is the third line of your code? Right after the two `import` statements?

Comment: @Amadan Damn!!! You're absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each time you open your file with `'w'` mode, it overwrites all the existing data in the file.

`read()` isn't doing this. To prevent this, open the file with `'a'` mode.

Answer (score 5):

When you do `jim = open('multiclipboardd', 'w')` at the top of your program, it truncates the original file and erases it. That's why your file's getting erased.

Also, when you open files you should `.close()` them or use a [context manager](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).

Comment: I did think about this while writing the code. But do you think that it is really useful? We're running this in the Terminal! not in the IDLE. It works perfect without .close()! Anyway, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @M.Hamel Yeah, it works, but you avoid problems in the long run. In longer code or in multiple programs that access the same file, you avoid race conditions, and other I/O errors. It really is worth getting used to using `.close()`

Comment: @M.Hamel Also, running it in the terminal or IDLE or any IDE doesn't matter. file objects still should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

`read()` is not truncating your file.

The unconditional `jim = open('multiclipboardd', 'w')` at the top of your file is.

If you don't want it to delete your content, replace the `'w'` with an `'a'`.